# Assertion Failure while trying to assert amount of textviews in a list

Tags: java, android, robotium

Why is my assertion failing when I am trying to assert the amount of textviews in a list ?

```
@Test
public void testDeleteNote() throws Exception {

   int count= getNoOfTextViews();
    // Checking if count is greater than 0.
    if (count > 0) {
        // Iterating count times
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // Checking if count is even or odd.
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                solo.clickInList(0);
                deleteNote();
            } else {
                // Clicking Long on the 1st item in the Notes List.
                solo.clickLongInList(0);
                // Clicking on Delete String.
                solo.clickOnText(solo.getString(R.string.menu_delete));
                }
    }

    count = getNoOfTextViews();
    // Asserting all the text views are deleted.
    assertEquals(0, count);
}

  public int getNoOfTextViews() {
    // Getting the count of text views in the activity.
    ArrayList<TextView> textView = solo.getCurrentViews(TextView.class,
            solo.getCurrentViews(ListView.class).get(0));
    return textView.size();
}
```

The failure I am seeing is:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<0> but was:<1>

UPDATE: 
I am seeing that this passes when i debugg, it fails only when i run the test case.

Comment: Please add more code. We can't know what is the variable `solo` and what are the methods `deleteNote()`, `clickInList()`, `clickLongInList()` and `clickOnText()`.

Comment: was able to solve this by adding wait for list view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `count` variable is calculated once at the beginning of your program and then never updated. This means, when you are comparing it with `0` at the end, it still contains the old value.

All you have to do is update your count variable by calling the method again:

```
count = getNoOfTextViews();
```

Or simply

```
assertEquals(0, getNoOfTextViews());
```

Comment: my mistake i copied it wrong. I'm using assertEquals(0, getNoOfTextViews()); . This case passes when i debug and fails when i run.

Answer (score 1):

Added a wait for list view before taking the count. This helped me solve the problem.

Thanks all.

```
public int getNoOfTextViews() {
    solo.waitForView(ListView.class,0,1000);
    // Getting the count of text views in the activity.
    ArrayList<TextView> textView = solo.getCurrentViews(TextView.class,
            solo.getCurrentViews(ListView.class).get(0));
    return textView.size();
}
```